# How to make this table using only HTML (tr, td, rowspan tags), (NO CSS)

Tags: html

I am using this code but it doesn't seem to work. Help. It just doesnt seem to work however hard I try.

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <table height="100%" width="70%" border="3">
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="1"> A </td>
            <td rowspan="2"> B </td>
            <td rowspan="3"> C </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2"> D </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> E </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> F </td>
            <td> G </td>
            <td> H </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

---

The above HTML renders as this:

[image]

...but I want it to look like this:

[image]

Comment: Why don't you want to use any CSS? Does that include `style=""` attributes? (Are you targeting late-1990s web-browsers for some reason?)

Comment: No, my younger brother is in 8th grade and he had this question in his test. He is only been taught HTML till date so I was wondering if this was even possible without CSS as I am no expert in HTML. Sorry if you can't understand me easily as I am not a native speaker as my name would suggest. Yes that includes style=" " attributes

Comment: It's possible (and without CSS), but I note that CSS is irrelevant because `rowspan` and `colspan` are not CSS properties and CSS cannot control them, and CSS cannot define the exact layout of a `<table>` by default (though it _can_ if you completely override it with `display: grid;` but that's off-topic).

Comment: The answer posted by @Richard was correct, I don't know why they deleted it.

Comment: Yes, they deleted it for some reason. But I still have the code.


<table border=3>
<tbody><tr height="25px">
                <td rowspan="1"> A </td>
                <td rowspan="2"> B </td>
                <td rowspan="3"> C </td>
            </tr>

            <tr height="25px">
                <td rowspan="2"> D </td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="25px">
                <td> E </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> F </td>
                <td> G </td>
                <td> H </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>

Answer (score 0):

It helps if you visualize the *raw* table rows in a diagram. I've indicated those in pink:

[image]

Then we can see that:

- `A` - no rowspan, no colspan.
- `B` - `rowspan="2"`, no colspan.
- `C` - `rowspan="3"`, no colspan.
- `D` - `rowspan="2"`, no colspan.
- `E` - no rowspan, no colspan.
- `F` - no rowspan, no colspan.
- `G` - no rowspan, no colspan.
- `H` - no rowspan, no colspan.

Let's start with a normal table without any rowspans (using `*` to denote cells that will be merged):

I've added a CSS rule to set `height: 50px` on all `<td>` elements for the sake of illustration. It doesn't affect the table's actual layout.

```css
tr > td {
    height: 50px; /* min-height on <td> doesn't work */
}
```

```html
<table height="100%" width="70%" border="3">
        <tr>
            <td> A </td>
            <td> B </td>
            <td> C </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> D </td>
            <td> B* </td>
            <td> C* </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> D* </td>
            <td> E </td>
            <td> C* </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> F </td>
            <td> G </td>
            <td> H </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Then let's add rowspans to the first row:

```css
tr > td {
    height: 50px; /* min-height on <td> doesn't work */
}
```

```html
    <table height="100%" width="70%" border="3">
        <tr>
            <td> A </td>
            <td rowspan="2"> B </td>
            <td rowspan="3"> C </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> D </td>
<!--        <td> B* </td> -->
<!--        <td> C* </td> -->
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> D* </td>
            <td> E </td>
<!--        <td> C* </td> -->
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> F </td>
            <td> G </td>
            <td> H </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Then let's add rowspans to the second row:

I've set different `height` values for each of the cells (in accordance to their `rowspan`), otherwise the middle row collapses (as there's nothing to prop it up).

```css
tr > td {
}

tr > td.a {
    height: 25px;
}
tr > td.b {
    height: 50px;
}
tr > td.c {
    height: 75px;
}
tr > td.d {
}
tr > td.e {
}
```

```html
<table height="100%" width="70%" border="3">
        <tr>
            <td class="a"> A </td>
            <td class="b" rowspan="2"> B </td>
            <td class="c" rowspan="3"> C </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="d" rowspan="2"> D </td>
<!--        <td> B* </td> -->
<!--        <td> C* </td> -->
        </tr>
        <tr>
<!--        <td> D* </td> -->
            <td class="e"> E </td>
<!--        <td> C* </td> -->
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> F </td>
            <td> G </td>
            <td> H </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

---

*Ta-dah:*

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. I tried a lot before I saw your post and came up with a working code too. Here it is- https://pastebin.com/Miaaj8nx